# Execute LIST HISTORY in IBM Data Studio

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

How can I execute the `DB2` command `LIST HISTORY` in IBM Database Studio?

Comment: No idea why this was upvoted - What have you tried, what is your code, what results do you want, etc? Add some substance to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [IBM Data Studio 4.1.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038173) you are able to execute all DB2 commands in the SQL editor view.

1. Open a SQL Editor
2. Select Tab `Configuration`
3. Change `Run Method` to `Command Line Processor`